# PHPMailer AddAttachment does not work

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I have the following... Mails are being sent without the attachment and I can't seem to find the reason.  Any help will be highly appreciated :)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Host     = "localhost"; // SMTP server
$mail->From     = $dwwp_email;
$mail->FromName = "Bla bla title";
$mail->addReplyTo($dwwp_email);
$mail->IsHTML('true');

$mail->Username = "some dorky username";
$mail->Password = "letmeinMan";
$mail->AddAddress($to);

$mail->Subject  = $subject; 
$mail->AddAttachment('../attach/tnc.pdf', 'TnC.pdf');
$mail->Body     = $message;

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Comment: try the full path to the attachment

Comment: No sir, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is check the return value of `addAttachment()`.  Per the [**documentation**](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment):

***"Returns false if the file could not be found or read."***

Assuming your file actually exists in the place you are referencing, check and make sure you (or whatever process is executing this code) have read privileges. And as commented above, using the full path is (probably) a good idea.

Additionally, it shouldn't matter but it's generally good practice to call functions with the same case as they appear in their declaration.  In two cases the class declaration differs from the way you wrote it (begins lower case):

```
$mail->addAttachment('/full/path/to/attach/tnc.pdf', 'TnC.pdf');
$mail->addAddress($to);
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself! The generated docs for the same thing are [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment). The case matching thing suggests the OP based their code on an old example - the case of various functions changed for better PSR-2 compliance a while back - and may be using an old version of PHPMailer too.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I wrote for myself and works perfectly fine with attachment of any kind.

**Post Parameters :**

```
1. from       -- from email id
2. subject    -- subject of email
3. message    -- message content of email
4. secret     -- UPqHPVAA7RV3eGZ1CySqAj1OM1eiurgbh8e7rgbergre87ge9rb
5. filename   -- name of file
6. path       -- path of the file
```

If You can replace the post parameters with normal PHP variables if you want or can simply post these parameters through POST call

---

Following is the code for my mailer file

```
$result = array();
if(isset($_POST['from']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['secret']) && isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['path']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['to'])){
            $to = $_POST['to'];
    }else{
            $to = "my_email@live.com"; 
}
$path=$_POST['path'];
$filename=$_POST['filename'];
$file = $path.$filename;

$content = file_get_contents($file);

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$secret = "UPqHPVAA7RV3eGZ1CySqAj1OM1eiurgbh8e7rgbergre87ge9rb"; //This is required to use this script. It ensures that only we can use this script.
$from = $_POST['from'];
$headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n";
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";    
$headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers.= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$headers.= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers.= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$headers.= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers.= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$headers.= "--".$uid."--";


if(strlen($_POST['secret'])!=100)
{
    $result['sent'] = FALSE;
    $result['error'] = "whatsmyname";//Malicious Script Use Attempt Thwarted.
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
if($secret == $_POST['secret'])
{
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        $result['sent'] = TRUE;
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $result['sent'] = FALSE;
        $result['error'] = "mailserver";//Mail Server Down.
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    $result['sent'] = FALSE;
    $result['error'] = "whatsmyname";//Malicious Script Use Attempt Thwarted.
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
```

}

You can create the message content in HTML format. Means You can add image to message content, color code your content and all the others things which you can do with html.
Following is the example of message body :

```
$message='<html>                            
          <body>
            <font size="3">Name : '. $name.' </font><br /><br />
            <font size="3">Email : '. $email.' </font><br /><br />
            <font size="3">Contact Number : '.$phonenumber.' </font><br /><br />
            <font size="3">Registration Date: '.$signupdate.' </font><br /><br />       
            <br />
            Thanks, <br />
        </body>
        </html>';
```

---

Cheers !!!!

Comment: This a classic example of why you should not roll your own email code. It's vulnerable to header injection attacks, will not work with UTF-8 data, is missing a subject header, does not encode headers correctly, forges from address (so will fail SPF checks), and acts as a spam gateway, amongst other things. Use a library.

Comment: if you know this much then i through you would be smart enough to take of that . The point here was to facilitate with one of the working mailer script and not to point out what vulnerabilities you can have. And along with that if you go through it properly , i have mentioned the subject header

Comment: Why do you think that suggesting that *anyone* uses unsafe code is a good idea? Writing code that does not have these issues is difficult; libraries exist so you don't have to. The OP is already smart enough to have figured that out.

Comment: @RiteshKumar - with all due respect, the `<font>` tag is deprecated, not supported in HTML 5 and, imo, should not be used in 2015.